# React useEffect + useState seems to initialize components before state variable defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-cognito

I am trying to attach a JWT token from AWS Cognito to Uppy requests in my upload component. To get the token, I believe I need an async function:

```
async function getSessionToken() {
  const data = (await Auth.currentSession()).getAccessToken().getJwtToken()
  console.log(data)

  return data;
}
```

However, I need the value of `getSessionToken` (ie. the actual token) before I initialize my Uppy component. To do this, I thought it would be best to use `useEffect`, whereby I could set the state of a variable using `useState` and render the Uppy component after `getSessionToken` returned a value:

```
  const [tokenData, setTokenData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(tokenData)
    getSessionToken().then((token) => { setTokenData(token) })
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {tokenData === 'undefined' ? <Skeleton variant="rectangular" width={210} height={118} />
        : <UppyComponent data={tokenData} />}
    </>
  )
```

where `UppyComponent` is:

```
function UppyComponent(props) {
  console.log(props.data)
  const uppy = useUppy(() => {
    return new Uppy({
      debug: true,
      autoProceed: false,
      restrictions: {
        maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
        minNumberOfFiles: 1,
        allowedFileTypes: ['video/*'],
        requiredMetaFields: ['caption'],
      }
    })
      .use(AwsS3Multipart, {
        limit: 4,
        companionUrl: 'http://localhost:3020/',
        companionHeaders: {
          'Authorization': "Bearer " + props.data,
          'uppy-auth-token': "Bearer " + props.data,
        }
      })
      .use(GoldenRetriever)
      .on('complete', result => {
        console.log('successful files:', result.successful)
        console.log('failed files:', result.failed)
      })
  })

  return <Dashboard
    uppy={uppy}
    plugins={['DropTarget']}
    inline={true}
    target='.DashboardContainer'
    showProgressDetails={true}
    note='Video only, up to 1 MB'
    width='400'
    metaFields={[
      { id: 'name', name: 'Name', placeholder: 'Give your work a title. ' },
      { id: 'caption', name: 'Caption', placeholder: 'describe what the image is about' }
    ]}
    browserBackButtonClose={false}
  />
}
```

However, I noticed that `UppyComponent` is still being initialized/rendered before `getSessionToken` returns. Looking at the requests, I see that `props.data` is still undefined in `UppyComponent`. I had thought, since useEffect wouldn't set the state variable until after `getSessionToken` returned, `props.data` wouldn't set until `getSessionToken` did as well. Is this not the case?

And is there a workaround?

Comment: You want `tokenData === undefined` or `typeof tokenData === 'undefined'` not `tokenData === 'undefined'`.

Comment: Btw, no reason to use that fragment around the conditional component.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this was the fix.

Comment: In terms of the extra fragment, I seem to be getting a syntax error when using VSCode if I don't include the fragment

Comment: Have you also omitted the `{…}` around the children of the fragment? `return tokenData === undefined ? <Skeleton … /> : <UppyComponent … />;` does work fine.